# Increase Max length of image name of Magento 2.3.5 error message:(was not uploaded. Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less)

Tags: magento

When I import product data or I upload image directly to a product I get the following message (was not uploaded. Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less)

Recently my magento has been updated and I didn't have this problem before.

Does anyone know how I can increase the number of characters slightly?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1BVR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem myself.

The file in question is located in the following folder
vendor\magento\framework\File Uploader.php

search for the following code:

```
// account for excessively long filenames that cannot be stored completely in database
if (strlen($fileInfo['basename']) > 90) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Filename is too long; must be 90 characters or less');
```

Adjusting this file is not the best method, I have to add

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you override that function?

Comment: // account for excessively long filenames that cannot be stored completely in database
        $maxFilenameLength = 200;

        if (strlen($fileInfo['basename']) > $maxFilenameLength) {
            throw new \LengthException(
                __('Filename is too long; must be %1 characters or less', $maxFilenameLength)
            );
        }

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question on Google, I wanted to share additional findings, as I've faced the same issue. Perhaps you will find them helpful.

As @Timo already wrote, the limit of `90 characters` is hard-coded in the `getCorrectFileName()` method in `vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php` (in older versions of Magento).

```
    public static function getCorrectFileName($fileName)
    {

        (...)

        $maxFilenameLength = 90;

        if (strlen($fileInfo['basename']) > $maxFilenameLength) {
            throw new \LengthException(
                __('Filename is too long; must be %1 characters or less', $maxFilenameLength)
            );
        }

        (...)

    }
```

Since this method is `static`, writing a plugin is not possible and apparently providing a preference won't work as well.

It seems that there was a fix for this [already available in Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/30011), but only in versions `2.4.2` and `2.4.2-p1`. Then, for whatever reasons [it got removed](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/db19d6d5250343371c3f85674d705c099628453c). See the [related Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29377).

[Since Magento v2.4.5](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/File/Uploader.php) the file name length is now limited to 255 characters:

```
    private const MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH = 255;

    (...)

    public static function getCorrectFileName($fileName)
    {

        (...)

        if (strlen($fileInfo['basename'] ?? '') > self::MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH) {
            throw new \LengthException(
                __('Filename is too long; must be %1 characters or less', self::MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH)
            );
        }

        (...)

    }
```

So, until you upgrade your Magento version to `2.4.5` or newer, it seems that making a change in the core code is the only option, either manually or using a composer patch.